# Does MSDASQL.1 support TLS1.2

Tags: ssl, odbc

I have my access files(.mdb) which contain connection to SQL Server 2012 using MSDASQL.1 as provider.
Through Citrix somehow, the connection gives SSL security Error, if we disable TLS1.0 as new version allowed is TLS1.2.
People are saying MSDASQL.1 is so old that it doesn't support TLS 1.2.
I did not get the information anywhere if MADASQL.1 supports TLS 1.2 or not.

My connection string is 
"Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & DSNname

However, it fails when we disable TLS1.0.
I have tried changing MSDASQL.1 to MSOLEDB, however, it needs server name. 
What we have in input instead is DSN name and it is spread across multiple tools, so we cannot change this style of getting connection string using DSN.

"Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & DSNname

Answer (score 0):

SQLNCLI11.0 got it working.

As an example, you can Create a DSN using below function

```
Declare 
Private Declare Function SQLConfigDataSource Lib "ODBCCP32.DLL" ( _
 ByVal hwndParent As Long, _
 ByVal fRequest As Long, _
 ByVal lpszDriver As String, _
 ByVal lpszAttributes As String) _
As Long
```

and put "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" as driver string;

Because, the New "TLS1.2" protocol requires you to have native client 11.0 to be installed on the machines and used aboveas the driver for ODBC and connection string.

Also, please note, some old versions of even native client 11.0 wont work on TLS1.0. so, better to have the latest one ew one.